# Deduce first type from second non-type parameter of first type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, type-deduction

I have following function:

```
/// <summary>
/// Check whether next character in std::basic_istream is what expected. Skip it if so; otherwise, set fail flag.
/// </summary>
template <typename TCharType, TCharType char_>
std::basic_istream<TCharType>& skipIf(std::basic_istream<TCharType>& istream_)
{
    if ((istream_ >> std::ws).peek() == char_) {
        istream_.ignore();
    }
    else {
        istream_.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    }
    return istream_;
}
```

It works like this:

```
std::istringstream is {"some ; string"};
std::string temp;
if(is >> temp >> skipIf<char, ';'> >> temp) {
    // blah blah
}
```

Is there way to deduce `TCharType` from given `char_` template parameter? It would be nice if I could write just

- `skipIf<';'>` -> deduced to `char`
- `skipIf<L';'>` -> deduced to `wchar_t`
- `skipIf<u';'>` -> deduced to `char16_t`
- `skipIf<U';'>` -> deduced to `char32_t`

Comment: C++17 is an option?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with C++17's new `auto` non-type template parameters. A bit of rearranging:

```
template <auto char_, typename TCharType = decltype(char_)>
std::basic_istream<TCharType>& skipIf(std::basic_istream<TCharType>& istream_)
{
    if ((istream_ >> std::ws).peek() == char_) {
        istream_.ignore();
    }
    else {
        istream_.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    }
    return istream_;
}
```

And you should get what you are after, exactly. You can probably improve it by adding a few more checks (either as a `static_assert` or SFINAE) to make sure `TCharType` is indeed one of the standard or extended character types, but that's the cookbook solution.

Comment: Lovely solution!

Comment: Note that `TCharType` would probably be deduced, and not necessary be `decltype(char_)`.

Comment: @Jarod42 - Fair point. Though one can force it into being a non-deduced context if that's a problem, or ditch the utility `TCharType` entirely, I just didn't want to force too much of a rewrite onto the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I would put a `static_assert(is_same_v<decltype(char_) , TCharType>,"dont play");` to make it as if the second argument never existed.